# ORACLE: How to alter table defaults with existing NULL values

Tags: oracle, nullable, alter

I have a nullable column with null values and I want to add a default constraint for only new inserts into the table.

My alter code:

```
alter table customer_02
modify reference default on null
'No References';
```

I keep getting error ORA-02296 meaning, I have null values pre-existing in the table so I cant enable my new default. How can I insert the default for only new inserts and not affect the previous data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
Update customer_02 set reference = 'No references' where reference is null
```

First

The entire column has to comply with the constraint; you can't have the old data remain null and then install a "not null" rule. You're saying it's ok for the references column to contain "no references" where it once contained null (meaning "no reference") so there shouldn't be any harm in updating those old null values so they're consistent with the new rule, then you can implement the new rule

If you desperately want to have old rows remain null while new rows cannot be null you'll need to use a (before insert) trigger that throws an error if the :new.reference column is null, and leave the column as nullable. I would avoid this for two reasons, one that it uses triggers and they're usually a bad way to get things done and two because it establishes a seemingly needless inconsistency that would puzzle future developers. As mentioned before, if null has fallen out of favour as the way to indicate there are no references, the old data should be adjusted. Keeping it null might also leave to errors elsewhere, if the front end expects a value - you might end up with your users experiencing crashes when they call up old records.

I'd recommend to always strive for consistency in data modelling, even if it means adjusting old data

Comment: In the end, you are right, and changing previous null's would make this ultimately easier and make more sense. Thank you!